# Cutting Fishnet OR Create Parcels in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, vector-grid, grids-graticules, parcel-fabric

What I need to do is the following task in ArcGIS (10.2): I downloaded shapefiles of different countries. For one of these countries, e.g. Austria, I need to define, eg. 400 squares, which means that afterwards Austria is separated in 400 (or any other number) of squares.

As far as I can see I can solve that problem with a fishnet. However, I have some problems with that:

I get to define a Fishnet in any number I want to but:

1. This number also includes an amount of squares which do not overlap Austria,
2. I don't know how to cut those squares that do not overlap the shapefile of Austria.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  The model for our focused Q & A here includes "one question per question".  Since parcel fabrics are an unconventional way to solve this problem (I don't even see how they could help), I'd recommend you focus on asking about the fishnet approach.  I will warn you that the computational complexity of finding an origin where exactly 400 squares overlap a country with an irregular outline will probably prevent you from finding an exact solution.

Comment: Couldn't you just clip your fishnet by the country boundaries? I don't see how a parcel fabric would be helpful here, though.

Comment: "Couldn't you just clip your fishnet by the country boundaries?" 

Thanks for your help!

This is more ore less what I want to do, but I don't know how :) And by that another problem arises: If I want a fishnet with 400 squares all over Austria, and I define my fishnet to be 20x20 squares, then I will have a lot of squares outside of Austria. Hopw can I get exactly 400 INTO Austria? :)

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but since you say, any number of other squares, does this mean you are fine with say 100 squares or 200 squares in Austria.  If so then you would create the fishnet and then clip the fishnet to your shapefile of Austria(or do a spatial selection all fishnets that are inside of Austria then export that out)  Then you would only have squares that reside in Austria,  You can play with the settings of the fishnet to get the size of the squares that best fits your data.

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)

This is more or less what I want. But I don't know how to cut the fishnet :) And another problem I mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: There are a few ways,  I think the easiest way would to be use the clip tool and clip the fishnet layer to the shapefile of Austria.  You can find clip in the seach for tools menu by typing clip, then clip the fishnet to Austria. (this is probably the best option) but you could also do a spatial selection, from the selection menu at the top, choose select by location, then choose all fishnets that are within the source layer (your layer of austria),  once arc has highlighted those contained fishnets then right click on the fishnet layer -> data -> export  to make a new feature class.

Comment: Finally to get exactly 400 I am not sure of an algorithm or way to do it other than playing with your sizes until you get them close enough to 400 that it suits your needs.  Maybe someone else knows a better way than that, i just dont

Comment: Cool! That helped a lot!! Thanks! Concerning the number of squares: Is there a tool, that can count the number of squares after clipping?

Comment: Look at the attribute table of the clipped fishnet, it will show you how many squares it has been cut into.  Just highlight them all and look at the bottom.

Comment: Great,  also you may want to keep the selection as a polygon and not a polyline when you do the fishnet, That will make polygons for each box, rather than intersecting lines.  And if this answer worked out for you please upvote it :)